# Ubuntu Linux 13.04 and Windows 8 don't like one another

Tags: boot, 13.04, windows

Well, I have done everything possible to ensure that all is well but to no avail.

- I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04.2 and 13.04 onto a HDD with UEFI *but all I get is the black screen.*
- I then tried `vga=normal nomodeset` at the end of the kernel line. *Nothing happened.*
- I then tried to install Ubuntu Linux 13.04 in the Legacy boot.
- I then ran boot-repair with the following from http://paste.ubuntu.com/5976834/. *Now I cannot get Ubuntu to log in.*

Any ideas out there?

Comment: It is not that they dislike each other it is Windows not being able to see Ubuntu and she panics when she realises something is on her hard drive/system that she can not work out. She is trying to keep herself to her self whereas Ubuntu is very promiscious. To get both OS installed using UEFI may involve specific steps for your machine.  What make and model machine are you using?

Comment: Have you tried kernel parameter - noefi?

Answer (score 0):

A very quick synopsis of what is required to get Windows and Ubuntu using UEFI to boot.

- If Windows already installed using UEFI boot to Windows and switch
  off fast start or any hibernation settings.
- Boot to firmware settings and switch off UEFI.
- Boot Ubuntu installation media and allow installer to run in legacy
  mode.
- Boot to firmware settings and switch on UEFI.
- Boot to boot-repairCD (not Ubuntu LiveDVD) and use this to install grub-efi.

If boot-repairCD does not boot using UEFI installing rEFInd may provide correct .efi drivers to enable booting boot-repairCD using UEFI.

Should now have dual booting system using UEFI. This is a work around due to Ubuntu installer unable to work using UEFI on some machines.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier for me to just reinstall windows 8 and ubuntu onto legacy mode?

Comment: @KeithD.Lee It takes 10 mins to run boot repair.  installing windows and then updates = 2hrs + and then about an hour additional for ubuntu = 3 hours plus.  Then start installing all your apps. Alternatively keeping windows as is  and installing ubunutu then updating.  A lot less time involved.  That is not taking into considering time backing up anything you wish to keep from both os's before reinstall..  You have both os's installed all you have to do is put bootloaders in the correct position according to partition table you choose to use.

Comment: Boot-repair should do both legacy to uefi and uefi to legacy conversion. So no need to reinstall completely jusyt use boot repair to fix the boot.  UEFI or legacy is the mode of booting so once OS is booted there are very few differences betweebn them

Answer (score -2):

Installing ubuntu in UEFI HDD is not that easy, i created a gude, but is too large to write it here, so I'm giving you the link.

It's in spanish, use google translate

[Guide for UEFI](http://tecnoubuntu.wordpress.com/2012/12/09/instalar-ubuntu-12-10-junto-a-windows-8/)

Comment: Or https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: It is highly recommended to use ubuntu.com for reference.  How about translating your guide and post in your answer? As this is an English site. Providing a link with very little indication what is in link is not an answer.  Links break and there is no other information here to be of use if the link did break.

Comment: As I said, it's too large for posting it here, I want to help, but if he is interested he will make an efford.